# PHP secure mail executing even when recaptcha verification fails

Tags: security, email, recaptcha

When entering the security words in recaptcha and clicking the Submit button, the PHP secure e-mail function is executed - even when the recaptcha verification fails and returns the error message.  The basic code follows.  What can I do to NOT execute the e-mail function?  Thank you.

```
<form name="contactform" method="POST" onSubmit="return validateCaptcha()"
    action="send_form_email.php">

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function (){
        Recaptcha.create(" --- my key ---_",
          "recpatcha_show",
          {
            theme: "red",
            callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
          }
        );
       });
</script>
      <div id="recpatcha_show"></div>
      <div id="captchaStatus" style="color:red;font:16px;"></div>
<br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"><a href="http://www.--- my url base ---/email_form.php "></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how recaptcha works, but I'm guessing you'll have to prevent the form from submitting when the chaptcha characters don't match.

With jQuery its:
`if(characters dont match){

    event.preventDefault();

} else {

submit form

}`

Also, you might want to read this:
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php?hl=nl

You can make recaptcha completely back-end, that way you can completly validate the user imput before sending the e-mail.